# How can I add a prefix to the column names of a join table in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, multiple-columns

I am joining two tables in T-SQL which have the same column names and I want to distinguish them not only via a reference but also I want to distinguish them in the resulting joined table.

I want to add a prefix for all the columns coming from the original or the joining table, e.g. Table1-Col1, Table2-Col1, etc.

Is there a quick way to do that so that I won't have to repeat all the columns one by one in the query?

Comment: There is not a quick way.  You need to do it one-by-one.

Comment: Copy/paste plus a little bit of Find/Replace with Regex should do the trick. This is in your IDE not as part of the actual running query obviously

Answer (score 0):

RE: "Is there a quick way to do that so that I won't have to repeat all the columns one by one in the query?"

Not sure how quick you will find the following.  I do this all the time with wide tables. Break even vs doing them one at a time is about 6 or 8 columns for me. Your mileage may vary.

1. Drag and drop the "Columns" tab under the table in ObjectExplorer into an SSMS query window. This gives a comma separated list.
2. Copy the comma separated list into Excel.
3. Use Data - Text to columns.  Converts comma delimited string to a set of columns in spreadsheet.
4. Copy columns to clipboard.
5. Paste Special with Transpose selected
6. Use CONCAT in a cell in the next column over to build a formula that creates column strings.  For example,

   *=CONCAT(", ", A17, " as Table1-", A17)*
7. Copy the formula to all columns
8. Copy the columns back to SSMS.  You will have an extra comma that needs to be eleted at this point.

As noted, I use Excel for these types of conversions regularly.